# Unable to use SimpleObstacleShadowing: No obstacles have been detected

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I loaded my SUMO files with all the necessary data, including net.xml, rou.xml, especially poly.xml for the buildings as obstacles and the .sumocfg. I used the omnetpp.ini from the example of veins, and adjusted some parameters such as set the number of accidents to 0,  and I ran into this issue that no obstacles were detected. Also I can't see any polygons in the GUI of OMNet++ after the scenarios is loaded.

I checked the poly.xml file, which is generated by the OSMwizard. and it shoul contains all the building polygons. Also I use the default setting. And it doesn't work

How do I where the problem started and how to debug this issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share the first 50 lines (e.g.) of your poly-file and your omnetpp.ini?

Comment: @thardes2 thank you for the reply. codes examples are as follow. poly.xml: `<poly id="1081837858" type="amenity.toilets" color="237,199,199" fill="1" layer="-1.00" shape="642...` and omnetpp.ini related to obstacles: `#Annotation Parameter *.annotations.draw = true #Obstacle Parameter *.obstacles.obstacles = xmldoc("config.xml", "//AnalogueModel[@type='SimpleObstacleShadowing']/obstacles")` Sorry that I didn't find a more efficient way to upload these codes and comments

Comment: The ```type``` needs to be ```building```